# Insert google analytics filters with App Script, permissions error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I have the following function:

```
function insertFilter() {

    var filter = {
      'accountId': 'XXXXXX',
      'resource': {
        'name': 'My Domain Filter',
        'type': 'EXCLUDE',
        'excludeDetails': {
          'field': 'GEO_DOMAIN',
          'matchType': 'EQUAL',
          'expressionValue': 'example.com',
          'caseSensitive': false
        }
      }
    };

filter = Analytics.Management.Filters.insert(filter, XXXXXX);
}
```

When running it I have the following error:

`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to analytics.management.filters.insert failed with error: User does not have sufficient permissions for this account.`

I'm working on my own account and I have the highest possible level of access.

What's wrong here? What do I'm missing?

Comment: i would check the account id again. The user you are authenticating with does not have access to that account.

Comment: I've already checked multiple time and that's the right account ID. I'm on Chrome, I'm logged with the same email that has access to the GA account (that is the GA account of my own website). Would it be possible that my script isn't authenticate on this email? how can I check that?